# Android: how do i prevent canvas to draw the whole view when animation

Tags: android, canvas

I hava a customized view and I draw its UI on its onDraw(Canvas canvas) method. I some case I need do some animation (anim is true)

```
public class GameView extends View {

//more code

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    canvas.drawBitmap(item.getBitmap(), item.getXY().getX(), item.getXY().getY(), null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(ResizedBitmapMapping.getHouse(), 0f, 0f, null);
    if(amin){
        canvas.save();
        canvas.rotate(currentValue);
        drawBall(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }
}
```

But the ball is very small, so only a small part of the view needs to be re-drawn. it should be a performance issue to draw the whole view. What is the right to draw such animation?

Answer (score 0):

What your are looking for is [Canvas.clipRect()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#clipRect(float,%20float,%20float,%20float)).

[Here](https://youtu.be/vkTn3Ule4Ps) is a short video from Google that explains how it works and how to use it. Alternatively, you can invalidate only a region of a view with [View.invalidate(int,int,int,int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)).